# How come Neiru hasn't revived her sister yet?

Tags: wonder-egg-priority

In *Wonder Egg Priority*, when Neiru is first introduced, it's established that she started buying Wonder Eggs long before Ai, and often buys several at a time. Despite this significant head-start, Ai manages to revive Koito before Neiru is able to revive her sister. In fact, as of the end of Episode 12,

> Neiru is the only one of the four protagonists who hasn't revived their loved one yet.

**How is this possible?** Did Ai really overtake Neiru in terms of Wonder Eggs hatched? Or did Neiru have a higher target to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the release of the special, this hasn't been addressed, however it *has* been revealed that

> Neiru is actually an artificial human similar to Frill, and that her "sister" was actually her creator, Airu.

It's *possible* that Neiru therefore required more Wonder Eggs, by virtue of

> not being fully human.

This is speculation, but it's the only logical explanation I can come up with.

(Considering that the special raises more questions than it answers, my honest opinion is that the writers just didn't think it through, but I wasn't originally looking for an out-of-universe answer so I'm keeping that opinion as a footnote.)